# Cryptowat.ch Embed API freezing all browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a local html file so that I can embed Cryptowat.ch's embed API into a desktop application through a webview.

[I have found an NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptowatch-embed) that demonstrates how to use the API, and it seems really easy. [It even comes with a sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2k0ahf1/1/).

Before digging into any of the customization I simply copied the JSFiddle to a local file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
        #chart-container {
            width: 550px;
            height: 186px;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="chart-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.cryptowat.ch/assets/scripts/embed.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadChart() {
            var chart = new cryptowatch.Embed('gdax', 'btcusd', {
                timePeriod: '30m',
                width: 550,
                height: 186
            });
            chart.mount('#chart-container');
        }
        window.onload = loadChart;

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in the JSFiddle, but it doesnt work in ANY browser I've had installed. On Chrome, I see the chart, but no data and the page becomes unresponsive. On Firefox I only see a black square. On Internet Explorer, it's just a blank page.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There simply seemed to be a momentary blip in the API.

I was experiencing the exact same issues as you described, using your above code.

Without modifying the code at all, it now appears to be working correctly.